# Avoid overwriting of build.xml by Codename One

Tags: codenameone

The answer to the question [Multiple Codename One CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480459/multiple-codename-one-css) works fine *(I prefer multiple CSSes than an unmanageable single CSS of thousands of lines...)*, but it relies on the fact that Codename One will not overwrite my manually edited `build.xml`.

How can I avoid at all that Codename One will overwrite that file? I set it as read-only, but I don't know if it's enough.

Moreover, is there any good reason to allow Codename One to overwrite that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is overwritten when we have new features that should be expressed there e.g. new build targets etc.

Before overwriting we prompt the user. So this would happen when you open Codename One Settings and save. You can always say "No". I suggest backing up the file and doing relatively simple changes.

One future change we intend to make is stripping the file of most of it's content similarly to the build.xml/build-impl.xml relation in netbeans. This will allow us to update the impl XML file seamlessly and allow you to customize the XML file.