# More than one CSS files in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I want to implement more than one CSS files in my codename one project which will help me avoid one file with very many lines of code. Kindly guide me on how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't builtin support for this but it was already discussed with a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480459/multiple-codename-one-css/53488737